# SVD - Linking right and left singular vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, svd

I'm working through the textbook [mathematics for machine learning](https://mml-book.github.io/) and have hit a sticking point in SVD. If the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ then, I understand how the right and left singular vector $V$ and $U$ are derived from the diagonalization of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$. However, the book states

> The last step is to link up all the parts we touched upon so far. We have
> an orthonormal set of right-singular vectors in $V$ . To finish the construction of the SVD, we connect them with the orthonormal vectors $U$ . To
> reach this goal, we use the fact the images of the $\mathbf v_i$ under $A$ have to be
> orthogonal, too. We can show this by using the results from Section 3.4.
> We require that the inner product between $A\mathbf v_i$ and $A\mathbf v_j$ must be 0 for
> $i \ne j$ . For any two orthogonal eigenvectors $\mathbf v_i$ , $\mathbf v_j$ , $i \ne j$ , it holds that:
> $$ (A\mathbf v_i)^T(A\mathbf v_j) = \mathbf v_i^T(A^T A)\mathbf v_j = \mathbf v_i^T(\lambda_j \mathbf v_j ) = \lambda_j \mathbf v_i \mathbf v_j = 0 .$$

My question is, how does the final equation go from $\mathbf v_i^T(A^T A)\mathbf v_j = \mathbf v_i^T(\lambda_j \mathbf v_j )$? How does $A^T A$ end up as a scalar value $\lambda$? Can somebody add a more intuitive explaination to the above?

Comment: What is $\lambda_j$ here? The eigenvalue of $A^T A$ corresponding to $\mathbf{v}_j$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember how the $v$s were defined --- they're the *eigenvectors* of the square matrix $A^T A$, so for each $k = 1, 2, \ldots, n$, there's a number $\lambda_k$ with
$$
(A^T A) v_k = \lambda_k.
$$
In particular, for $k = j$, we have
$$
(A^T A) v_j = \lambda_j.
$$

Just to be clear, you've said that they arise from "the diagonalization of $M = A^TA$," and it may not be clear that this makes them eigenvectors. Well, suppose that
$$
Q^{-1} M Q = D(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)
$$
a diagonal matrix with numbers we'll call "$\lambda$s" on the diagonal. Then multiplying through by $Q$ we get
$$
MQ = QD
$$
If we call the first column of $Q$ by the name $v_1$, then this can be read as saying, by equating the first column of each side, that
$$
Mv_1 = Q \pmatrix{\lambda_1\\0\\ \vdots \\ 0} = \lambda_1 v_1.
$$
and similarly for other columns. In other words, when we diagonalized $M$, the diagonalizing matrix $Q$ has the property that its columns (which we call $v_1, v_2, ...$) are each eigenvectors, with eigenvalues being the corresponding entries of the diagonal matrix $D$.

Comment: Thank you John. I'd clearly overlooked the most basic concept of $Ax = \lambda x$, which in this case is $(A^T A)x = \lambda x$